# How to conditionally chain in jQuery without specifying a shorthand else statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, filter, chaining

I have a list with linked or no-link items, so the HTML looks like this:

```
<ul>
 <li>
   <a href="#">
     <img />
     <h3>Hello</h3>
     <p>World</p>
   </a>
 </li>
 <li>
   <img />
   <h3>Foo</h3>
   <p>Bar</p>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to wrap everything inside the list item (or list item link) that is not an image.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
// inside a loop over the listitems
var item = items[i];
var containsLinks = item.children.length === 1 && item.children[0].tagName === "A";

// this does not work...
var captionsContent = $( item ).children()
    .filter(containsLinks ? "a" : null)
    .not("img")
    .wrap( "<div class='ui-captions-content'></div>" );

// neither does that
var captionsContent = $( item ).children()[containsLinks ? children : null]()
    .not("img")
    .wrap( "<div class='ui-captions-content'></div>" );
```

**Question**:
How do I "null" the return in a shorthand if-else statement in jQuery or how do I do a conditional chaining without the shorthand else-statement?

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just pass a bad selector?

Comment: How to do? (I think I'm learning something now... :-)

Comment: `$( item ).children().has('a').not('img').wrap()` ?

Comment: @jAndy: does not work. Wraps `["a"]` and `["h3", "p"]`, when it should wrap `["h3", "p"]` and `["h3", "p"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
var captionsContent = $( item )
  .find(containsLinks ? "a *" : "*")
  .not("img")
  .wrap( "<div class='foo'></div>");
```

Short and barring a better answer, I will live with it.